# How to define On Change function dynamically using loops in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTMl loaded like this:-

```
if(isset($company_admin))
{
    $tot_admin = count($company_admin);
    for($i = 0; $i < $tot_admin; $i++)
    {?>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Admin Image <?php if($i > 0) echo ($i+1);?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="hidden" name="hid_admin_img[]" id="hid_admin_img<?php if($i > 0) echo '_'.($i+1);?>" value="<?php if(isset($company_admin[$i]['admin_img'])) { echo $company_admin[$i]['admin_img'];} ?>">
             <input type="file" name="admin_img[]" id="admin_img<?php if($i > 0) echo '_'.($i+1);?>" class="form-control"></br>
        <div id="imagePreview3<?php if($i > 0) echo '_'.($i+1);?>"></div>
        <div id="existImage3<?php if($i > 0) echo '_'.($i+1);?>">
        <?php if(isset($company_admin[$i]['admin_img'])) {?>
            <?php if($company_admin[$i]['admin_img'] != ''){?><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/admin_org/<?php echo $company_admin[$i]['admin_img'];?>" height="100" width="100"><?php } else {?><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/new-user-image-default.png" height="100" width="100"><?php } }?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php
  }
}?>
```

When an image will be selected, the imagePreview div will reload it to show the preview.

Here's a basic sample of what I was doing.

```
$("#admin_img_2").on("change", function()
{
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file
        reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            alert("hii");
            $("#existImage3_2").hide();
            $("#imagePreview3_2").show();
            $("#imagePreview3_2").css("background-image","url("+this.result+")");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I have to write one function each for $("#admin_img") based on the counter.

I want to implement the same using some dynamic approach like using a counter:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i = 2; i<=4; i++)
    {
        $("#admin_img_"+i).on("change", function()
        {
            var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
            if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

            if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
                var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

                reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                 $(this).closest("div[id^=existImage3_]").hide();
                 $(this).closest("div[id^=imagePreview3_]").show();
                 $(this).closest("div[id^=imagePreview3_]").css("background-image","url("+this.result+")");
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});
```

But somehow, its not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the HTML with common classes and the bind the event handlers. In the event handler, use the relationshio between the element and use various DOM traversal method to target desired element. Here in example [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is used.

*HTML*

```
<input type="file" name="admin_img[]" class="admin_img form-control">
<div class="imagePreview"></div>
<div class="existImage"></div>
```

*Script*

```
$(".admin_img").on("change", function() {
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    // no file selected, or no FileReader support
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
        return;
    }
    // only image file
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {

        // Cache the current element context in a variable
        var _this = $(this);

        // instance of the FileReader
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // read the local file
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

        // set image data as background of div
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            _this.siblings("existImage").hide();
            _this.siblings("imagePreview").show().css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        }
    }
});
```

---

As per you current HTML. Your DOM traversal methods are not correct. and In `onloadend` event `this` does't refer to `input` element thus it doesn't works.

*Script*

```
//Bind event based on name attribute
$('[name="admin_img[]"]').on("change", function() {
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    // no file selected, or no FileReader support
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) {
        return;
    }
    // only image file
    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {

        var _this = $(this);

        // instance of the FileReader
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // read the local file
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

        // set image data as background of div
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            _this.parent().find("div[id^=existImage3_]").hide();
            _this.parent().find("div[id^=imagePreview3_]").show().css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry! Can't use class in this approach. There is some CSS related issue and using any class(even with no extra css) is causing design getting distorted

Comment: @Saswat - How could adding a class name with no associated CSS rules cause any distortion? Seems to me your page has bigger problems than the one you asked about.

Comment: @nnnnnn Maybe he has Javascript that's doing `if(element.className == "something")`. That would break with extra classes.